# Asp.net MVC 4 How to enable Migrations from DbContext in another Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, dbcontext, n-tier-architecture

My Project has 3 tiers:

- Project.Core: Entities and Repositories Interfaces.
- Project.Data: DbContext, Repositories implementation and UnitOfWork implementation. Has reference of Core.
- Project.UI: Views, Controllers, ViewModels. Has reference of Code and Data.

I'm using MVC 4 with Entity Framework 5 and Code First Approach.

So It's possible to enable POCOs Migrations on Project.UI?

I Tried run:

> enable-migrations Project.Data.MyDbContext

But receive the message:

> The context type 'Project.Data.MyDbContext' was not found in the assembly 'Project.UI'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you are running enable-migrations on the project containing your DBContext so you cant run it on the UI project (otherwise it needs to be a relative path to the project from the currently selected one eg. ./project.data)

[image]

Set default project to `Project.Data`

then run:

`enable-migrations`

Answer (score 0):

You can also include the Project.Data.DLL to the Project.ui this is the approach we have taken. We have also wrapped views into a similar DLL for use across multiple projects

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a separate project within your solution for data seeding.  You can then include a reference to your Project.Data.DLL within the seeding project and run the migrations from there (which would be fitting).